# How to password protect a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I execute docker run command or docker exec command, it doesnt ask for any password. Is there any way to ensure that when we enter docker exec or run command, it always asks for the password?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this.  Docker containers generally don't have "users"; to the extent that they do, they almost never have passwords set; and you don't "log in" to them, you just run a command.

For example, a typical command to get a debugging shell

```
docker run --rm -u root --entrypoint /bin/sh -it imagename
```

*directly* runs the interactive shell, as root, with no checks.  Docker jumps straight into the `sh` process; there is nothing before it that would have the possibility of checking a password.

If you're trying to use this as a way to hide the image's contents, you can't.  Anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can access any file in any container, and can pretty much trivially root the entire host system.

Comment: Can't this be done by customising the ~/.bashrc or the ~/.profile file for the root user of the container? For example, we can add a simple script which can ask the user for their credentials. In case the credentials are incorrect or something failed while executing that script, the docker container will exit gracefully. Is this not a fail safe solution?

Comment: The specific `docker run` command I have here won't read any shell dotfiles.  You don't need an interactive shell; you can `docker run ... imagename ls /app` to poke around some, and that path doesn't use a shell at all.

Answer (score -1):

What is it that you want to achieve/avoid by introducing a password? Which Operating System are those container running on? Debian / Ubuntu / CentOS / Fedora / Windows ...?

You could look into sudo privileges.

Here you can specify that user X is allowed to use sudo with his user password to run any docker command. Depending on your OS you could specify this in the `/etc/sudoer` file or via `visudo`.

Comment: Hi. The container is running on a CentOS machine. I have few python scripts in my container and would like to restrict the access to those scripts. Currently any user can use docker run or exec command to view the contents of the container. I am trying to see if I can enforce a password prompt every time someone enters docker run or exec command on the container. Thanks

Comment: how do the users of your CentOS machine interact with docker? Are they part of the `wheel` group, have you created a `docker` group, is everybody able to `sudo` at will? Please go into more detail on your docker is installed and configured on your CentOS machine.

Comment: The container has some python scrips which will be triggered manually be me. Other users are not supposed to be interacting with the container. I will be logging inside the CentOS machine once in a while, start the container and execute few scripts. So my concern is that since the container is loaded into the CentOS user, someone with the credentials for the CentOS user can view the scripts by docker exec command as it doesnt ask for a password specific to the container. The CentOS user is a part of the wheel group.

Comment: Since I dont have much control over the CentOS user permissions, I am trying to ensure that accessing the container requires some level of password protection. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you won't be able to protect your scripts. The container image is freely available on the machine, all users share access to the docker commandline and you do not have the permissions to secure docker on the machine running docker